# Detect user visibility for Yahoo

Tags: yahoo, yahoo-messenger

How can I detect if a yahoo user is online or offline? I got connected to the yahoo server but I dont know what kind of packet to send to yahoo and then where in the received packet I can find the information about the user?

Thank you.

Comment: Can you add some more information about your environment, language used, etc?

Comment: I'm not going to post this as an answer, but the wikipedia page for the [Yahoo Messenger Protocol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yahoo!_Messenger_Protocol) contains links to various YMSG implementations. you should be able to find what you need there

Comment: I am using c++ under windows, i read the wikipedia page but with no help, i can't fidn anywhere the steps that i need to follow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to try using [libyahoo2](http://libyahoo2.sourceforge.net/) (or reading the source), they also have [partial YMSG9 protocol documentation](http://libyahoo2.sourceforge.net/ymsg-9.txt) which may be insightful.

Answer (score 0):

For detecting user online offline status programatically, i dont have any idea. But  I can suggest a way out, if you can do it programmatically.
We detect user by the chat environment in yahoo. If your partner is appearing offline, then from chat window we try to load environment. If environment gets loaded 100% on the other end then the user is in invisible mode else he is really offline.